# Powershell workflow command not recognized

Tags: powershell, workflow

I'm using Powershell v2.0 on a remote machine and I created a workflow there using the following code:

```
workflow install {
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
[string]$currentLocation
)
... 
}
```

I've tested on my local machine, where I have Powershell v3.0 and it's working, but on the remote machine I'm getting this error:

```
The term 'workflow' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Install\Longitude\Longitude Components\Install.ps1:6 char:9
+ workflow <<<<  install {
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (workflow:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: this shows little effort on your part, considering that 90%+ of websites describing powershell workflows specifices that it's a 3.0 feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workflow is a new feature of Powershell v3, it's not available in v2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow, I missed that detail :)